# How to edit blog page in wordpress? there is no place to put shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I have a shortcode  I want to put on the sidebar which appear only on the blog page and the single post page.

so I created a field for this shortcode using Advanced custom fields plugin.

when I went to the blog page, I have not found the field or any place to add the shortcode to the sidebar on the blog and blog single.

what should I do, please?
and many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I doubt most of the Wordpress themes have the in-built functionality you're needing.

You will have to check out your theme's `single.php` file and find out if it's including a sidebar template (it should), check that template and make sure it has the necessary action/hook to programmatically insert custom elements into your blog and blog posts sidebar.

Several themes actually have both **before_** and **after_** *sidebar* actions, but i can't guarantee yours has it (if not, you'll probably have to create a child theme or a custom plugin to begin with).

After you've managed to determine the correct action to be used, you'll have to add some code (into functions.php - probably a child theme's - or a custom plugin) to output your custom field's value.

In example, if your theme provides an action called `my_theme_before_sidebar_items`, you'll see something like this:

```
do_action( 'my_theme_before_sidebar_items' );
```

And you'll be able to use the above action this way:

```
add_action( 'my_theme_before_sidebar_items', 'my_custom_function' );
function my_custom_function() {
    // This will handle blog posts' sidebar. You might need a different approach to handle your blog's sidebar
    global $post;
    echo do_shortcode( get_field( 'my_custom_field', $post->ID ) );
}
```

Of course, the above `my_custom_field` is the example reference name for your ACF field.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. this is a theme I am trying to develop. I created a custom sidebar called main-sidebar. it appears on the website. when I go to the wordpress dashboard, and add widget to it, it is added but not visible on the website. I tried the same shortcode on the footer on frontpage and it worked.but not visible on the footer on the blog and the sidebar on blog. what should I do in this case?